# How to write such alternating series in the form $(-1)^na_n$ in order to establish convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you tell me how to determine convergence of the series :

$a) 1- \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^5}+...$

$a_{2k-1}=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}, \ \ a_{2k}=- \frac{1}{3^{2k-1}}$ ?

b) $a_{2k-1}= \frac{1}{2k-1}, \ \ a_{2k}=- \frac{1}{3^k}$
In general, what should I do when I'm given terms of a series in the form $a_{2k-1}=*, \ \ a_{2k} = *$ (Not necessarily alternating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the series $=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\left(\frac12\right)^r- \sum_{0\le s<\infty}\left(\frac13\right)^{2s+1}$

Both are convergent as the common ratios of both the [Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)  $<1$

In fact, we can calculate the exact sum to be $$\frac1{1-\frac12}-\frac{\frac13}{1-\frac1{3^2}}$$

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand why you substitute k-1=r, 2k-1=2s+1.

Comment: @Andrew, $\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\left(\frac12\right)^r- \sum_{0\le s<\infty}\left(\frac13\right)^{2s+1}=\sum_{0\le k<\infty}\left(\frac12\right)^k- \sum_{0\le k<\infty}\left(\frac13\right)^{2k+1}$

Comment: @Andrew, I changed to $r,s$ to point out that the two series are independent & can be calculated separately.

Comment: All right, that I understand. I'll try that approach for the next examples. Thanks :)